# Is a Wheatstone bridge with 5 nodes possible?

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, voltage

The statement of the question is to find $R_x$

I think most Wheatstone bridges are of 4 nodes where if a detector is connected in between two nodes, then when the potential difference across the nodes is zero, it can be open-circuited. So my questions regarding this problem are:

1. If the circuit is balanced can I directly remove the galvanometer even though it has 5 nodes?
2. If not, why does a Wheatstone bridge with 5 nodes demand it be solved by converting the upper right part of the circuit so that the overall circuit is of 4 nodes?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Think of a galvanometer as something that measures a property of the circuit without changing the circuit.
2. I expect the purpose of the problem is to make you think about how series and parallel resistors can be combined. This obviously isn't the simplest circuit you can make, and you probably wouldn't build one this way. But thinking about it might teach you something about how to simplify circuits.

Comment: Problem that's been bugging me is that since galvanometer detects small amout of current so if there were 4 nodes i could directly say that this circuit is balanced and i can work around it but since there is 5th node that's not allowing me to do so.

Comment: If a Wheatstone bridge is balanced, there is a simple equation that tells you things about the resistors. Perhaps you need to think about where that equation came from. Perhaps it will help to think about currents through resistors and the voltage across them, and what you know about how currents and voltages behave.

Comment: If it were 4 nodes i could solve this problem by making a thevenin equivalent circuit because thevenin open circuit voltage measures difference of voltage between two nodes and if that is equal to zero, that's how we get balanced condition of any wheatstone bridge.

Comment: You haven't said what the problem is. But I would guess you are asked to calculate $R_x$ that makes the circuit balanced. By balanced, I expect the galvanometer reads $0$. If that is true, that should tell you something about the currents and voltages. That is about all the help I can give. We don't provide answers to homework problems at this site. Just help with the concepts.

Answer (score 0):

I understand the question to be "Which value of Rx makes the bridge balanced?"

So my reasoning path is: I assume the bridge to be balanced (which allows me to do some circuit simplifications), and then I find out that most Rx values contradict this assumption, and only one does not, so this must be the answer.

If the bridge is "balanced", that means that there's zero voltage across the galvanometer.

A branch with zero voltage across it can be replaced by an open non-connection, a direct connection, or a resistor of whatever value you prefer, without changing the circuit's behaviour. So, you can remove the galvanometer. But if you later find out that, for a given Rx value, there's a non-zero voltage between the two nodes, then that's a contradiction, meaning that this Rx value must be wrong.

Or, to put it another way, you now have to find out which Rx value makes the voltage zero.

Now, what are the two potentials (voltages against a common node, e.g. the battery "minus" connector) at the two nodes? And which value of Rx makes them equal so the zero-voltage condition holds?

Comment: My university professor told me that this circuit is balanced but i will try checking voltages before and after solving the question.

Comment: Thanks i really appreciate your feedback i tried finding values of $R_x$ but it was only possible through making it from 5 to 4 nodes and found that at $R_x$=33.33$\Omega$ the open circuit voltage between that node came 0.00005000V which i think sums up that without 4 nodes we can't solve the wheatstone bridge problem.